# Custom result error in play.api.mvc.BodyParsers (scala)

Tags: json, scala, model-view-controller, playframework

I'm using play.api.mvc.BodyParsers for my Scala project. But the thing is if parsing fails, it always throws default error result like "Json validation error...". What I want to do is to send my custom Result in case of json validation failing.

```
def myAction = (authAction)(parse.json(myObject.reads)) { request =>
   //some code here
   Ok
}
```

Let's say that if myObject parsing fails, I want my result to be Forbidden("invalid params in myObject"). Is there any way do that without checking request.body.myObject after parsing "succeed"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Instead of parsing in the action's body parser argument, you can instead parse inside the action's code block:

```
def myAction = (authAction)(parse.json) { request =>
  request.body.validate[MyObject](MyObject.reads) match {
    case JsSuccess(myObject, _) =>
      //some code here
      Ok
    case JsError(_) => Forbidden("invalid params in myObject")
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.